# For any $n$ there's a power of $2$ which contains $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

So I saw this problem in an Olympiad book, 
"Prove that for any natural number $n$, there exists a power of $2$ which contains $n$ in it. "

For example, $n=19$ is in $2^{13}=8192$, $n=24$ is in $2^{10}=1024$.

I tried solving it by Pigeonhole principle, but haven't made any progress. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd look for a power of two that starts with the digits of $n$.

Comment: This should be a duplicate. Your claim follows from the fact, that the fractional part of $k\cdot log_{10}(2)$ is equidistributed in the interval $[0,1]$ and therefore $2^k$ can begin with every finite digit string (that does not start with $0$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick sketch of a proof:

1. Prove $\log_{10}(2)$ is irrational.
2. Prove that the fractional part of $n\alpha$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha$ is irrational, is dense in $(0,1)$
3. Note that the fractional part of $\log(x)$ determines the first few digits, and then use the density of the fractional part of $n\alpha$ to prove that the first few digits of the number can be any $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

If you need more help, just ask!